# jQuery POST waits for response before processing user interaction with anchors

Tags: php, jquery, post

Let's say I have a simple jQuery POST script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post("post-data.php")
        .done(function (data) {
            // Done function
        }).fail(function () {
            // Fail function
        });
});
```

Let's say I have this HTML:

```html
<div id="page">
    <a href="link.php">Some link</a>
    <div id="jquery-data-response"></div>
</div>
```

If post-data.php returns data after 10 seconds and I click on "Some link" within  10 seconds, the page "link.php" is loaded after the jQuery POST request is completed, so the user has to wait for a maximum of 10 seconds.

This applies to jQuery GET requests as well.

Now I have two questions.

1. Where is the problem? Is it a Server issue (let's assume that the script is fully optimized and can't be faster than 10 seconds, it happens on localhost with XAMPP too), a jQuery issue (a missing function that handles user-interactions?) or a browser issue (does Chrome have to wait before all requests are processed?)?
2. Is it possible to solve this issue (and how)?

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the problem?

The issue at hand is how you manage interactions independently of the request. If you don't want someone to click a link before a request has been fulfilled, then you should manage that until it does.

For example, declare a flag in your code that determines whether or not your request has been resolved. Defaults to `false`. Then run your ajax query. Upon success, it will set `requestComplete` to `true`.

```
let requestComplete = false;

$.post("post-data.php")
  .done(function (data) {
    // this will prompt your listener to allow native execution
    requestComplete = true;
  })
  .fail(function () { ... });
```

Bind a listener to your link(s) that only allows interaction if the flag is `true`. The return value of an event handler determines whether or not the default browser behaviour should take place as well. In the case of clicking on links this would be following the link.

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function (event) {
  return requestComplete;
});
```

And so your markup will look something like this:

```
<div id="page">
  <a href="link.php" class="link">Some link</a>
  <div id="jquery-data-response"></div>
</div>
```

To demonstrate the blocking of a browsers default behaviour, explore [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuebizzle/ts1hrgan/).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation and examples! I wasn't clear enough in my own examples. It is about getting data instead of posting data (just changed it to a GET on our server), and we'd like to allow users to navigate to a different page, even if the server didn't respond yet). Is that possible?

Comment: Yes that's possible with the example you've given. You have a link, and you're doing a POST/GET request in the background. Users can still click on the link and navigate. But what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The problem is that, with the current situation, the user has to wait before the GET request is finished. If a user clicks on a link and the GET request is still in progress, the browser keeps loading till the GET request is finished.

Comment: Are you using sessions in your php scripts? I ask only because I think this is a server side issue and not client side. You’re unable to navigate to another page because php may be locked in a state and is waiting release before the next request can be processed.